# Swift SpriteKit SKVideoNode only plays once

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skvideonode

Hi I'm trying to play video on an SKVideoNode in swift
this is my code that works but  it only plays once if i click on VideoSprite it doesn't play but dose print "we Clicked the video" I've searched but can't seem to find an answer thanks for looking

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameScene: SKScene
{
    var VideoSprite = SKVideoNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {
        LoadVideo("9.mp4")
    }

    func LoadVideo(FileToPlay:String)
    {
        VideoSprite =  SKVideoNode (videoFileNamed:FileToPlay)
        VideoSprite.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
        VideoSprite.name = "VideoSprite"
        VideoSprite.zPosition = 2
        addChild(VideoSprite)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {
        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>)
        {
            var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
            var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
            if (node.name == "VideoSprite")
            {
                println("we Clicked the video")
                VideoSprite.play()
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027648/how-do-i-control-playback-of-a-video-in-an-ios-sprite-kit-skvideonode

Comment: hi thanks for the reply I've looked at that thread  i tried    `if VideoSprite.paused == true
                {
                    println("we are Paused")
                    //VideoSprite.removeFromParent()
                }   `   but it don't print

Comment: Do you want to restart the video when the video node is pressed? Or did you want to pause the video when it's pressed?

Comment: hi thanks for your reply I'm trying to restart thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hi I think I've cracked it 
i add another videoSKnode on top and rename it so the user can't click on the original video then after a delay i remove it 
this delay needs to be the time the video runs
i use a cool function for delay i found on the internet can't remember where from so thanks to who ever wrote it
 i hope this might help somebody else
i tried the paused bool in the update function but no luck?

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
class GameScene: SKScene
{

 var VideoSprite = SKVideoNode()// emptey Videonode

    func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->())// function for delay
    {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {

    LoadVideo("9.mp4") // run function to load video
    VideoSprite.pause()// pauses video ready to play
    }

    func LoadVideo(FileToPlay:String)
    {

        VideoSprite =  SKVideoNode (videoFileNamed:FileToPlay)// fill spritenode with video file
        VideoSprite.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);  // set size
        VideoSprite.name = "VideoSprite" // give it a name
        VideoSprite.zPosition = 1 // set its z position
        VideoSprite.play()// play video
        addChild(VideoSprite)// add video node to the sceene
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {
        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>)
        {
            var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
            var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
    println(node.name)

            if (node.name == "VideoSprite")// we click on video
            {

                LoadVideo("9.mp4") /// load another video ontop
                VideoSprite.name = "temp" //name it temp so user cant click to add more videonodes
                delay(1.8 )// wait for time
                    {
                     self.VideoSprite.removeFromParent()// then remove
                     }

            }
        }
    }



}
```